# Redux Saga Delay Ends Early

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I cannot figure out the delay effect in Saga.  It seems straightforward, but the timing is not working for me.  This is a React Native project.

```
import {take, race, delay} from 'redux-saga/effects';
...
function* letsRace(retryTimeout) {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const {resolved, timedout} = yield race({
        resolved: take('HAPPY_TIMES'),
        timedout: delay(retryTimeout),
    });
    if (resolved) {
        console.log(`[CBlock] : Good : ${Date.now() - startTime} / ${retryTimeout}`);
    }
    if (timedout) {
        console.log(`[CBlock] : Bad : ${Date.now() - startTime} / ${retryTimeout}`);
    }
}
```

Logs:

> [CBlock] : Bad : 4028 / 5000

> [CBlock] : Bad : 7045 / 8000

> [CBlock] : Bad : 16 / 800

No matter the delay I specify, the delay ends about one second early.  If the delay is less than one second, it seems to fire almost instantly.

Versions:

```
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.1"
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2"
```